# When should I import a header to Prefix.pch?

Tags: objective-c, ios, header, header-files, prefix

I've heard importing a header to Prefix.pch can improve performance as it will load the header once, instead of on each instance. So when is a header imported enough times in a project to warrant being included in the Prefix.pch? A dozen times? Several times? Just twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically add a header to Prefix.pch if it is being #imported into more than 3 classes. I don't think there's a rule of thumb - it depends on your own standards for what you consider clutter, elegance, how globally the code is used etc. For example, most of my projects have a Utilities.h and Utilities.m where I declare helper functions used in many places. I always add Utilities.h to my .pch.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to avoid the temptation of chucking too much stuff in the .pch. In particular, it obfuscates the dependencies in your code. Suppose you want to see where your code is using `AFNetworking` lib (for example): You search for the `#import` statements, and then see that the .pch file imports it, which tells you... nothing.

If when using a module/lib you usually import a number of related header files you can create a new header file that just imports the glob of related headers and then import that instead.